# Create nomogram with a given formula in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to get predictions using a nomogram and a formula given on a new dataset, which is  logit(p)=4.62536+0.24559×anion.gap+0.61542×lactate−1.04993×calcium+0.02687×BUN−1.76330×Chronic.renal.disease−0.05633×DBP

Below is the image of the monogram

[image]

I know nomogram can be created in R using function nomogram() of package "rms" but that functions can only be used with a trained model fit object. All I have at the moment is just the monogram and the equation above. Is there any way to create a nomogram based on the equation above?

Comment: The chart you're showing is a nomogram. Given this chart, a patient with anion = 14—that's 0 points (top number line), lactate = 6—that's about 50 points, calcium = 8—about 62 points, BUN = 100—about 52 points, chronic renal disease = yes—0 points,  diastolic = 70—44 points. That total is 50 + 62 + 52 + 44 = 208 points. You can draw a line straight down from the position on the total points bar to the risk of mortality. You can predict that this patient's risk is about 50%.

Comment: @Kat yes I know but as I need to make predictions for a huge amount of data then I wonder if there is any way to recreate the monogram above in R to calculate, except estimating the ratio between the lines.